# grub not finding hwe kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel, 22.04

I'd like to try the hwe version of the 22.04 kernel in an attempt to fix some non-working hardware (built-in speakers) . I installed the hwe kernel with the 'mainline kernels' GUI and it seems to be on my system, but grub isn't picking it up (see below) - how would I now boot into the hwe kernel?

```
jr@jr-Legion-7-16IAX7:~$ sudo apt list --installed |grep linux-headers
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-6.7.6-060706/now 6.7.6-060706.202402230933 all [installed,local]
linux-headers-6.7.7-060707/now 6.7.7-060707.202403011350 all [installed,local]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.5.0.21.21~22.04.11 amd64 [installed,automatic]

jr@jr-Legion-7-16IAX7:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.7-060707-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.7.7-060707-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.6-060706-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.7.6-060706-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Comment: "Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-21-generic" seems to be picking it up just fine.  To boot to it you will need to select Advanced then select it from the list in GRUB.  Grub considers the mainline Kernel 6.7 to be newer than 6.5 so unless you modify the GRUB_DEFAULT= in the /etc/default/grub file then GRUB will always boot to 6.7 by default.

Comment: I think the 6.5.0-21 generic is the non-hwe kernel, I'd like to use the hwe kernel which is 6.5.0.21.21.   That one doesn't show up in the advanced grub list which is why I checked the update-grub list, which finds four of the five kernels that the `apt list  --installed` finds, the missing one being hwe.

Comment: I use the HWE Kernels and I am running 22.04.4 LTS.  The versions mine has installed are exactly the same as yours.  `linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.5.0.21.21~22.04.11 amd64 [installed,automatic]`  And yes, it shows up in the list as `6.5.0-21-generic`.  My `uname -a` returns `Linux terrance-ubuntu 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.  So, as I can see it, you have exactly what you are looking for.  Beyond that, I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: A mainline kernel is not a HWE kernel.

Comment: @Terrance I think you (and I) are possibly running the non-hwe kernel; if you were running the hwe I think the uname would show hwe.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't install a HWE kernel "with the 'mainline kernels' GUI".

You have a mainline kernel installed. It has a higher version than the HWE one. Grub always picks the highest one be default.

Remove the mainline kernel and you will boot with an  Ubuntu kernel by default.

Install a HWE kernel by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

Comment: I added the hwe kernel frmo cli at some point , so possibly that part of my question is incorrect  - in any case I've been choosing the 6.5.0.21 and not 6.7 version in an attempt to start the hwe kernel; after removing the 6.7 kernels and choosing default , I get a boot hang so I think what's happening is the hwe kernel hangs the boot while choosing 6.5.2.21 gets me the non-hwe, which would explain why I never see the hwe kernel at `uname -a`

Comment: 6.5.0-21 is the current HWE kernel. Maybe the kernel was not installed properly, or some hardware is incompatible, like old Nvidia.

Comment: And `uname` doesn't "show HWE". `pilot6@Pilot6:~$ uname -a
Linux Pilot6 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
` This is the current HWE.